# How does ninject doing Dependency injection in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

i studying by the book Pro asp.net mvc2 by apress, In the book the author uses ninject for dependency injection.
He inherits the default control factory :

public class NinjectControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory

and then overrides : GetControllerInstance

I have 2 questions.

1. how does the DefaultControllerFactory knows what controller to load ? i assume he uses the route table and then loads it with reflection. am i correct ?
2. and how the ninject knows to do it, the only line i wrote is :

   private IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
   return (IController)kernel.Get(controllerType);

Ninject can't possibly know about my route table and which control he should load ..
so how does he knows ?

ps.
i use the regular ninject, not some specific version that created for MVC (which i believe they have on their website also)

Answer (score 0):

this is for mvc3 but a good article about ninject and mvc.
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Experience-ASP-NET-MVC-3-Beta-the-New-Dependency-Injection-Support-Part1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

NinjectControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance gets called by MVC. This means it is MVC that evaluates which controller type is required to process a request and it get it from the routing table.

If you want to use this I recommend using https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc It will save you time and work as it is maintained together with Ninject. Otherwise you will have to update to new Ninject versions yourself.